# Populate Visualforce page inputfield based on picklist value

Tags: jquery

I wanted to populate an inputfield in VF page via Jquery based on a picklist value. Any inputs on how to achieve this....just missing out of syntax i believe...

```
<apex:inputfield value="{!Opportunity.StageName}" id="stagename" onChange="setProb()" ></apex:inputfield>
<apex:inputfield value="{!Opportunity.probability}" id="oprprob"/>
```

my script code is:

```
<apex:includescript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.jquery, 'js/jquery-1.11.3.js')}" />
<script>
function setProb(){ 
 //oprstage();
 jQuery( oprprob ).val = 10;
}
</script>
```

Can i refer the value picked from the list and based on it set the values for the other input field?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your selector is not correct. You can use this to select the "ID Ends With"

```
function setProb(){ 
 jQuery( "[id$=oprprob]" ).val(10);
}
```

Comment: tried it but couldn't see it working

Comment: See updated answer. Confirmed working

Comment: thk u vry much eric